# Is minimizing $\Vert \! \log(y)-X\beta \Vert_2^2$ and $\Vert y-e^{X\beta} \Vert_2^2$ the same?

Tags: statistics, optimization, exponential-function, regression, least-squares

I am trying to fit some exponential data ($y$ is the regression target vector, and $X$ is the data matrix, $\beta$ is the coefficients that we want to optimize).

However I am getting different results from minimizing $\Vert \! \log(y)-X\beta \,\Vert_2^2$ and $\Vert y-e^{X\beta}\Vert_2^2$.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no surprize that the results are different.

Consider a simpler situation of a constant regression, i.e. minimizing $||y - c||_2^2$ over constants $c\in \mathbb R$. It is easy to see that the minimizer is the sample mean of $y$: 
$$
\hat c = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n y_i. 
$$
For logarithms, 
$$
\hat a = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \log y_i.
$$
So there is no reason to expect that $\hat c = e^{\hat a}$. In fact, by the Jensen inequality, $\hat c\ge e^{\hat a}$, and the inequality is strict unless $y$ is constant.

---

From the practical point of view, you are fitting different models to your data. Minimizing $||y-\cdots||_2^2$ presumes the Gauss–Markov assumptions, in particular, homoscedastic errors, while minimizing $||\log y-\cdots||_2^2$ assumes that the variance of errors is proportional to response (in other words, it assumes homoscedastic *relative* errors).

Comment: thanks, i think I am not really fully understand the regression assumption on "error" and probabilistic view. the first step for me is trying to understand why optimising different things are getting different numbers, which I thought they are equivalent. your example definitely helped me!

Comment: @hxd1011, you are welcome. And I strongly recommend you to try to grasp the assumptions behind different models, e.g. a linear regression. The understanding of these assumptions is crucial for their applications (and arguably is more important than knowing the particular statistical algorithms).

Comment: thanks again, and I asked a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466212/what-is-the-objective-function-to-optimize-in-glm-with-gaussian-and-poisson-fami). you are helping me to learn more.

Comment: I learned regression from "machine learning" literature and never have a comprehensive understanding of GLM model. I am learning from you guys.

Comment: @hxd1011, the problem with ML is that it often gives very little attention to interpretation, as opposed to the classical inferential statistics: in ML, a model is good as long as it fits data well.

Comment: @hxd1011, I think the discussion under the link is more about overfitting, while by "model fits well" I also mean the ability to generalize to new data. My point here is slightly different. Say, I know that using least squares for heavy-tailed data is wrong, and even more wrong if errors increase with response. But an average ML practitioner will not care as long as the fitted model generalizes with suitable prediction quality (this is, unfortunately, true not only for ML but also for many other applied studies). But this is a long story, let's not go off topic :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108288/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-hxd1011).

Comment: really liked your answer. could you further enlighten me [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685234/why-i-am-getting-similar-beta-for-minimization-sum-i-logy-i-x-i-beta2)