# Why I am getting similar $\beta$ for minimization $\sum_i (\log(y_i)-X_i\beta)^2 $ and $\sum_i (y_iX_i\beta-e^{X_i\beta})$?

Tags: statistics, optimization, exponential-function, regression, least-squares

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684859/is-minimizing-vert-logy-x-beta-vert-22-and-vert-y-ex-beta-vert) and learned that minimizing $\Vert \! \log(y)-X\beta \Vert_2^2$ and $\Vert y-e^{X\beta} \Vert_2^2$ are different.

But I still have difficult times to understand why minimization $\sum_i (\log(y_i)-X_i\beta)^2 $ and $\sum_i (y_iX_i\beta-e^{X_i\beta})$ will get "similar" results on $\beta$.

Could anyone show me why?

Comment: In the last expression, should there be a square?

Comment: @zhoraster no. I think it is the likelihood for poisson regression, details can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466212/what-is-the-objective-function-to-optimize-in-glm-with-gaussian-and-poisson-fami)

Comment: @zhoraster please correct me if I am wrong. But I carefully checked on the code. May be it has something to do with Poission can be approximated with Gaussian when lambda is big engouh?

Comment: I would then rather expect similar results with $||y - e^{X\beta}||^2_2$ due to log-link: both models have $\log \mathrm E[y\mid X] = X\beta$. In contrast, minimizing $||\log y - X\beta||_2^2$ is about  $\mathrm E[\log  y\mid X] = X\beta$, which is different. So why the results are similar is beyond my understanding.

Comment: But on the other hand, as I already wrote in the linked answer, minimizing $||\log y - X\beta||^2_2$ is about constant relative errors, and the Poisson glm shares this property. This might explain the similarity.